# Select x last rows before LIKE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a long mysql query that I'm trying to improve a little bit.
Basically, it takes scraped headlines from different news sources and match any TV shows in our database to it.
headline table
 "Game of Thrones renewed "
should match
"Game of Thrones" in the shows table.

It currently runs at 35 seconds (not so good; slow):

```
 SELECT
    news_feed.title,
    shows.name,
    shows.id,
    news_feed.news_id,
    news_feed.created_on
  FROM news_feed
  JOIN shows ON news_feed.title
     RLIKE CONCAT(
         '(^|[[:blank:][:punct:]])', shows.name, '($|[[:blank:][:punct:]])'
     )
```

By the looks of it, I could improve it by telling it the number of news_feed.title to look at. How can I add something like "`ORDER by news_id DESC LIMIT 50`" so it executes it before the `RLIKE CONCAT`?

I think doing this should be enough to make it run an acceptable amount of time? (it runs fives times a day so it's not that big of a deal as long as it doesn't crash the whole server)

Comment: Most likely only the news headlines will change and less the TV shows. Therefore once a headline as been processed you could link the TV shows to it (e.g. with a foreign key relationship) preventing it to be parsed again. This would also allow you to create aggregates of the TV shows much faster.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the bit of code after that. They only need to be matched once. Thanks

Comment: Then do that only for those news_feed rows that have no link to a TV show so far. Regular expressions in Mysql (and elsewhere) tend to be expensive, so only do when needed (really needed, not guessed based on order and some magical number e.g. 50 as in the answer :D - it might work, it might break. Just saying)

Comment: I can only agree with hakre. By all means look for a solution in that direction.

Comment: @mchl This isn't a query that a visitor can execute. It indexes the scraped headlines a few times every day and creates nodes between the headlines and the tv shows. There won't ever be more than a few thousand shows which means that the query won't ever take more than a second to execute but even then, it runs five times a day so it's not that big of a deal, right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. No point in overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a subquery that will limit the number of rows to be compared.

```
SELECT
    sq.title,
    shows.name,
    shows.id,
    sq.news_id,
    sq.created_on
FROM (

    SELECT
        news_feed.title,
        news_feed.news_id,
        news_feed.created_on
    FROM
       news_feed
    ORDER BY  news_id DESC LIMIT 50

) AS sq
JOIN shows ON sq.title
     RLIKE CONCAT('(^|[[:blank:][:punct:]])', shows.name, '($|[[:blank:][:punct:]])')
```